# Excel or Access Count Occurrences

Tags: excel, vba, ms-access, count, duplicates

I prefer a solution in Access but it not then Excel, I have investigated both but am struggling to find a solution. Here is the situation:-
In Access - 7 tables linked with unique keys. Each table has a postcode, I need to find out how many duplicated postcodes there are. There is no lead postcode to compare against. So for example:-

> RM9 6BG,RM9 6BG,RM10 9PL,RM9 6BG,RM9 6SR,RM9 6BG,RM9 6SR

Result would be:-

> RM9 6BG = 4
>   RM10 9PL = 1
>   RM9 6SR = 2

Sometimes tables could have no value for the postcode if this happens I do not want these counted as part of the duplicate groupings/counts.
There are 30+ thousand records.
Please no comments about normalisation...

Equivalent in Excel:-
The Conditional Formatting for "find duplicates" works on the first row but this only highlights them it does not group and count them, also it would need to be added to 30+ thousand rows? I have tried various CountIf's but no success.

All solutions welcome including VBA.

Comment: you can get it using pivot tables.....use postcodes in Rows and count of postcodes in values.....

Comment: Welcome to SO.  The community can help you with programming errors.  If you post your code, we'll help you fix it.  SO is not a code writing service.  If you want me to write code for you I'll charge you my hourly rate!  See [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: You may try Pivot Tables for this purpose. In Excel, insert a Pivot Table and drag the Postcode to Row Area and drag Postcode to Value Area. And it will give you the list of all the unique Postcodes and their count.

Comment: Thank you for your pivot suggestions. These provide counts of unique entries in a column, but I'm trying to get counts of duplicates in a row across 7 columns.

Comment: This question's wording is confusing, so I may be entirely wrong here, but can you just do a UNION query for each of the 7 tables to get all the postal codes into one column, then do a GROUP BY query on the result?

Comment: @Johnny Bones Sorry my question is confusing, I'm finding it hard to explain. Union then grouping would provide counts per postcode per column same as the pivoting. For my example "RM9 6BG,RM9 6BG,RM10 9PL,RM9 6BG,RM9 6SR,RM9 6BG,RM9 6SR" each post code separated by a comma would sit in it's own column forming a row, there are another 30+ thousand rows. I want to group the duplicate post codes across the row and count how many in the group.

Comment: Please show the query that joins all 7 tables. I side with @JohnnyBones that you *can* `union` query with outer `group by` for counts. You may be joining by some type of ID or `where` clause.

Answer (score 0):

Without having a full grasp on your table structure (i.e. field names/table names/etc...) I think the only way you're going to achieve this is to do the following:

1. Ensure you have a Primary Key/Unique ID for each record.  This may require you to put an Autonumber field into your table.
2. Perform a Transpose query for each record, so that you go from:

   UID......PC1..............PC2................PC3................PC4...............etc....

   1..........RM9 6BG.....RM9 6BG.......RM10 9PL.......RM9 6SR

to

```
    UID        PostalCode
    1          RM9 6BG
    1          RM9 6BG
    1          RM10 9PL
    1          RM9 6SR
```

3. Perform a UNION query on each Transpose (I'm betting you'll have to do this in a loop because there's no way you can have a SQL string long enough to do that 30,000 times)
4. Perform a GROUP BY query on the result, and count each Postal Code for each UID.

I don't know how you could do that in a more elegant way. I mean, it's not all horrible because you can do each step in a loop (For X = 1 to 30000, Select * where UID=X, etc...) and then just append the result to a table rather than actually doing a UNION query.  Then a GROUP BY query on the result table will get your numbers.

Answer (score 0):

@Jonny Bones Thank you for your time on this, I came up with the a solution as follows:-
I created a single string of all the fields (Postcode) in a row, then used a function that counted the amount of times a field (Postcode) appeared in that string.

Comment: Was thinking that you could use an array, but I've only tried that in Excel using the SPLIT function and then looping through (count and store each unique postalcode).  I'm guessing that SPLIT could work in Access too.  I'm guessing you used an INSTR function against the concatenated string of all the fields, and that works too, and then placing the postal code in a results table.